# Spring Boot multi-module unit test for service

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, multi-module

I have multi-module spring boot micro-service architecture like this:

```
<modules>
        <module>commons</module>
        <module>dao</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>api</module>
</modules>
```

Here I have put my **Application.java in API module**, which is having all the configuration. Now I want to test my service class methods but I am not able to add the configuration.

Do I need to write separate configuration or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: What is the purpose of having api, service and dao in different modules? The solution is putting them all together..

Comment: I have a similar situation with structured modules according to the domain, and the question is still valid.